# crmlistcomponent won't activate with Service Pack 1

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution, dynamics-crm

I recently had the task of standing up a new SharePoint 2010 Foundation server to use with the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 List Component](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5283).

I stood up the server, installed SharePoint Foundation and SP1, then followed the instructions at http://wellytonian.com/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-and-crm-2011-integration/.

At this point, I received the following error when trying to activate the sandbox solution:

> The worker process executing this request was killed because it exceeded the resource ProcessCPUCycles.

I tried a number of things including rebooting the server, creating a new web app, increasing the User Code Quota to its maximum 999999 points, and uninstalling SharePoint and installing it without SP1.

In the end, I was able to get the component to activate and connect CRM successfully only after completely rebuilding the server and installing SharePoint Foundation without SP1.

So, my question is: How can I get the crmlistcomponent to work with SP1?

**EDIT**

The crmlistcomponent has begun exceeding the quota under very light usage (this is on a QA server, where only one person is currently connecting via CRM).

Answer (score 1):

The User Code Quota does not help much if you exceed the Absolute Limits, you exceeeded the ProcessCPUCycles limit. Why that happened is another question, could be a lot of reasons. I have seen Sandboxed Solution working perfectly on low "spec" servers, and for some weird reason working terrible on high spec servers for unknown reasons. Probably a hardware issue at some level, I have no clue on stuff like that.

Anyway, you try and change these limits. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615462.aspx for overview of the different limits.

Example powershell for changing CPUCycles:

```
$userCode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUserCodeService]::Local
$cpuCycles = $userCode.ResourceMeasures["ProcessCPUCycles"]
$cpuCycles.AbsoluteLimit = 200000000000
$cpuCycles.Update($true)
```

Is this recommended in the long run, probably not :)